# Update - MvvmCross iOS with storyboards - TableViewCell not being displayed

Tags: ios, xamarin, storyboard, mvvmcross

I am trying to display a table view whose table view cells have a label in it. I followed MvvmCross N+1 days with N=3 to create this sample.

The table is being displayed, but the label is not being displayed

I have a MvxTableViewController

```
partial class View : MvxTableViewController
{
    public View (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

        var source = new MvxSimpleTableViewSource (TableView, typeof(CellView), "CellView");
        TableView.Source = source;
        var set = this.CreateBindingSet<View,ViewModel> ();
        set.Bind (source).To (vm => vm.CellViewModels);
        set.Bind (source).For (s => s.SelectionChangedCommand).To (vm => vm.ViewCommand);
        set.Apply ();

        TableView.ReloadData ();
    }
}
```

and an MvxTableViewCell with a label in it

```
partial class CellView : MvxTableViewCell
{
    public CellView (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
        this.DelayBind (() => {
            var set = this.CreateBindingSet<CellView, CellViewModel>();
            set.Bind(cellLabel).To(vm => vm.TextToDisplay);
            set.Apply();
        });
    }
}
```

As I said the table view is displayed but the label is not displayed in the cell. I can click on the table view and navigate to another view by binding to a command on my view model.

In the log I am getting the following warning

```
MvxBind:Warning: 13.35 Failed to create target binding for binding Text for TextToDisplay
```

I don't understand this, as the binding code looks OK to me!

There is one difference in the code from the N+1 N=3 video in that I am using the following code to construct the view source as I do not have a nib/xib

```
var source = new MvxSimpleTableViewSource (TableView, typeof(CellView), "CellView");
```

where "CellView" is the identifier entered in the properties for the prototype cell

Could this be the problem. I should also say I am using Xamarin Studio on a Mac.

Please help I have been banging my head against this for hours.

**Update - I have had to abandon the use of Storyboards due to rapidly approaching deadlines. Have reverted to using xibs for views and cells. If anyone solves this problem please post your answer**

Comment: Can you provide more trace - e.g. any just above the "Warning" you have included? My suspicion is that `cellLabel` is `null` when the binding is created.

Comment: I can't check just now, but will in the morning. Is there a method I need to overload where the cell can be created?

Comment: Maybe some kind of `awakeFromNib` equivalent for storyboards? (Best bet is to ask a more general question about when outlets are available in storyboards - that's an iOS thing - not mvx or xamarin specific)

Comment: I have had to abandon the use of Storyboards due to rapidly approaching deadlines. Have reverted to using xibs for views and cells. If anyone solves this problem please post your answer